# Shell - unzip file and set permission for all files

Tags: linux, permissions, zip

I have zip file created on windows and I want to extract it on Linux. For extracted files, I want to have permissions 644. However, extracting files end with 770.

I have tried

```
umask 644
unzip update.zip -d .
```

But it has no effect and permissions of extracted files are still 770.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? It would seem `unzip` is unaffected by `umask`. One could of course `chmod` after extracting, but that either requires a separate folder files are extracted to or knowledge of archive contents.

Answer (score 2):

Your `umask` mode is wrong.

```
# umask 644
# touch test1
# stat -c "%a %n" test1
22 test1
```

To get resulting files with `644`, you need to set `umask 0022`.

```
# umask 0022
# touch test2
# stat -c "%a %n" test2
644 test2
```

From `man umask`:

> umask()  sets  the calling process's file mode creation mask (umask) to
>          mask & 0777 (i.e., only the file permission bits of mask are used), and
>          returns the previous value of the mask.

Comment: Even with the correct `umask 0022`, it would seem `unzip` is unaffected.